# Power BI DAX: Subtracting one hour from SELECTEDVALUE datetime

Tags: datetime, powerbi, dax, subtraction, hour

I am using the following measure (and a calendar table) to determine equipment uptime for a given hour of the day based on user input from a datetime slicer:

```
Selected Hour =
CALCULATE (
    'UptimeView'[Uptime %],
    FILTER (
        'UptimeView',
        'UptimeView'[LocalShiftDateHour] = SELECTEDVALUE ( 'CalendarTable'[DateTime] )
    )
)
```

This is working just fine. The problem is that I also need this same calculation performed for *each* of the 12 hours *prior to* the selected hour. When I try to use the same formula but with one hour subtracted from the SELECTEDVALUE, like so...

```
S-1 =
CALCULATE (
    'UptimeView'[Uptime %],
    FILTER (
        'UptimeView',
        'UptimeView'[LocalShiftDateHour]
            = SELECTEDVALUE ( 'CalendarTable'[DateTime] ) - ( 1 / 24 )
    )
)
```

... I get blank cells in my table visualization, even though I know there is data for that hour:

[image: table screenshot]

Why does this happen? Any time I try to perform mathematical operations on the SELECTEDVALUE datetime value, it gives me blanks. But without using operations to manipulate it and just using the selected datetime itself, it works no problem. Is it not possible to subtract an hour from a SELECTEDVALUE datetime? If not, what workaround(s) should I try? (I have also attempted using `-TIME(1,0,0)` instead of `-1/24` but that gave me blanks as well.)

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is that the subtraction you are operating isn't convenient to go row by row. Would you please try rather to put it as follows, and put the MAXX() function around the calculus you did, while adding another argument, which is the name of the table in which you want the subtraction to be performed:

```
S-1 =
CALCULATE (
    'UptimeView'[Uptime %],
    FILTER (
        'UptimeView',
        'UptimeView'[LocalShiftDateHour]
            = MAXX('Replace_with_Tablename',SELECTEDVALUE( 
                                               'CalendarTable'[DateTime] ) - ( 1 / 24 ))
    )
)
```

This is the trick I use. In fact, `MAXX(tablename, expression)` Evaluates an expression for each row of a table and returns the largest value.

Don't worry about the max, it doesn't have any effect on the result, since the `max(one precise value in a precise row)= that same value`

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Unfortunately I'm still getting blanks, even when using MAXX as you instructed.